# is base64 encoding url safe?

Tags: node.js, url, base64

I'm using a node.bcrypt.js hash returning hex numbers in node.js for a password reset token.

```
user.reset_password_token = require('crypto').randomBytes(32).toString('hex'
);
```

Should I also base64 encode the token before I pass it around in urls (ie: link reset email)?

Is there any benefit to doing this?

I seem to recall base64 encoding can contain forward slashes which would mess up the path:

```
   var token = user.reset_password_token;

   //is there any benefit to doing base64 encoding?
   var encoded_token = new Buffer(token).toString('base64');

   var reset_link = 'http://example.com/reset/'+ encoded_token;
   sendResetLink( reset_link );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url (no, points out non-URL safe characters), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228701/code-for-decoding-encoding-a-modified-base64-url (talks about modified version)

Comment: Here is an *old* answer I wrote [for an alternative way to address this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395706/base64-encoding-that-doesnt-use-plus-or-equals-characters/4395900#4395900) that only requires a trivial pre/post replacement step for a variant base64 escape-encoding that doesn't require non-alphanumeric ASCII characters.

Comment: If your token is simply the hex representation of 32 random bytes, there is no need to do any additional encoding.  Hex characters (0-9A-F or 0-9a-f) are perfectly fine as-is. Personally I would not bother with double encoding.
Remember: those Hex characters are already an encoding of the binary data.

Comment: As to your questions about Base64 encoding (not that you need to use it here), you are correct that the "stock" Base64 character set includes 2 characters that would cause troubles if passed around in URLs.  The alternative Base64 encoding called Base64url simply replaces those 2 troublesome characters with two safe characters.  Namely, a "+" is replaced with a "-" and a "/" is replaced with a "_".  So, plus to minus, and the forward slash "lies down" to become an underscore.  There are a lot of places where base64url encoding / decoding are already available.

Comment: If your token is simply the hex representation of 32 random bytes, I would not bother with double encoding. Remember: those Hex characters are already an encoding of the binary data.
So, if you *do* perform some Base64 encoding, then if what you stored server-side was the 32 random binary bytes, you'll have to: a) base64 decode which will give you binary data, then b) reconstruct the hex character string from the binary data, then c) decode the hex string to the original 32 binary bytes. All to no purpose. Just send the hex string in the URL. It will be fine.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) can indeed contain forward slashes, but [base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#RFC_4648_Base32_alphabet) can't!

Comment: Does this implicitly imply that it base64 is unsuitable for URIs (e.g. are they *invalid*)? Or does it simply that handling needs to be different?

Comment: look at the set of possible characters. if you do not change the available characters used for encoding, then a cell could (theoretically) equate to a value of 64, which would give you a / in your string. Change the charset for your base64 function or use base32

Comment: Thanks, do you think there is any benefit to using base32 encoded string, instead of the un-encoded token?

Comment: base32 encoded strings will take up more room than base64 ones since there is only half the characters to encode with, i see no benefit, no :)

Answer (score 15):

You don't need a third-party library for that. You can just use `base64url` encoding (starting from `nodejs v14.18.0`)

```js
const encoded_token = Buffer.from(token).toString('base64url');
```

Comment: Does not work on my side, the base64url library works like a charm

Comment: I don't know when it was introduced exactly but v14.19.1 can handle base64url

Comment: v14.18.0 https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/buffer.html

Answer (score 7):

I solved it using URLSafeBase64 nodejs LIB at https://www.npmjs.org/package/urlsafe-base64

```
var email =email_lines.join("\r\n").trim();
var base64EncodedEmail = URLSafeBase64.encode(new Buffer(email));
gmail.users.messages.send({userId:"me",
        resource: {raw:base64EncodedEmail} }, callbackFn});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [base64url library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64url):

```
base64url("ladies and gentlemen we are floating in space");
// bGFkaWVzIGFuZCBnZW50bGVtZW4gd2UgYXJlIGZsb2F0aW5nIGluIHNwYWNl
```